# Which way of setting fields value is better and why?

Tags: java, optimization, constructor

This question can be stupid, but I just want to know, is there any difference?

```
class A{
    // common code
    private int field;
    public void setField(int field){
         this.field = field;
    }

    //way 1
    public A(int field){
        this.field = field;
    }

    //way 2
    public A(int field){
        setField(field);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Way 2 is better because it gives you a unified way of setting a variable value. But it brings in a risk, because you're calling an overrideable method in a constructor. So the right syntax is using the final keyword:

```
public final void setField(int field){
     this.field = field;
}

//way 2
public A(int field){
    setField(field);
}
```

With `final` the method will not be overriden. If you can not afford to have a final method, don't call the setter in a constructor. But it's usually strange to override a setter.

This is good because you may want to change the setter later:

- Add argument checks and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when required.
- Add a counter
- Notify observers (in an Observable pattern)
- Make it a synchronized block to provide thread-safety
- ...

And you will have to do it in a single place. This is an implementation of [DRY principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```
public final synchronized void setField(int field){
    if (0 <= field && field <= MAX_VALUE) {
        this.field = field;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }   
}

//still has all the benefits of setter
public A(int field){
    setField(field);
}

A = new A(-1) //throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Don't worry about the optimization and expenses of extra method call. JVM can usually optimize such code by inlining methods.

What really makes development slower is searching for a bug. This method helps you make less mistakes and easier maintain your code.

Comment: But isn't invocation a method makes it slower?

Comment: There might be a security risk of calling a public overridable method inside your constructor

Comment: @NickVolynkin sorry. 125 reputation is required, 123 actually)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ready. But -1 now, idk why. I just upvoted one time and now downvoted.

Comment: @NickVolynkin sorry. First time get this privilege)

Comment: @dkatzel fixed, please check.

Comment: @NickVolynkin that's fine.  An alternative is to have a private method do all the validation and actual setting and call that private method from the constructor and the also modify the public non-final setter to delegate to the private method too.  But your way is probably better

Comment: @dkatzel yes, I wanted to include a variant with delegate. But it still seems strange to let override a setter, especially if it uses checks etc. Maximum what I could allow is onSet(int value) method, (called from the shielded setter), which can be overriden in children.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect there is no "better" way, just want suits your purpose at the time.

I prefer **Way #1** much of the time.  This is because I try to make code as  [Encapsulated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) as possible.  It also can, in ways, be considered a [Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) way of programming Java, since you are reducing side effects.  Sometimes eliminating them all together.

```
class A{
// common code
private int field;
public void setField(int field){
     this.field = field;
}

//way 1
public A(int field){
    this.field = field;
}
}
```

Can be rewritten as...

```
class A{
// common code
private final int field;

//way 1
public A(int field){
    this.field = field;
}
```

Yes, it will not work if you need to change the value of *field* after instantiation.  Also may be *field* another object or collection.

But in the effort of making the class as **immutable** as possible, the fields that can be marked as **private final** are done so.

And of course you can't do that with a setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to me, way one is More Java. what I mean is that, we should know what should constructor do (to set up instances properties at the initialization time) and what should setter do (provide a public open point to change the the instance properties at the time you want).

we shouldn't place any logic in the constructor

just my opition.